# What does save as template mean in azure devops pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I created a new pipeline from the classic editor without YAML.

[image: New Pipeline on Azure Devops]

[image: Create a classic pipeline without YAML]

I now have a pipeline named **AspNetCorePipeLine**.

[image]

The question is what does Save as template do? What is its purpose and where is it saved?

Comment: It is used to save current pipeline as a custom template, then you could use it when you create a new pipeline. Shayki Abramczyk`s answer should be the correct direction, check if it helps you, if yes, you could accept it as answer, if not, let us to know more info about this issue.

Comment: I think he wants to know where it is, so he can edit the actual content of the template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you save a build template you can use it later when you will create a new build pipeline:

[image]

It's very useful when you have a few similar pipelines (but the better thing is to use YAML).

Comment: When I try to use the templete from another project in the same organization, it's nowhere to be found. Is there any way to save a template cross-project?

Answer (score 1):

Scope of Saved template of pipeline is within project.

So if you want to use same pipeline in another project or organization use Export option in pipeline to export it and you will get exported json file and then use this exported json file to create new pipeline in another project or organization by using import option.