# How to delete a saved pipeline template on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have created a pipeline and saved a template as shown by the link below.

How can I now **delete** the saved template?

[What does save as template mean in azure devops pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508804/what-does-save-as-template-mean-in-azure-devops-pipelines)

[image]

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check the pic, the delete button is next to Apply button.

[image]

Comment: Wow... it's completely white now (on a white background) unless you hover over it.  You really have to have already known it was there!  Best UI decision ever.